# trying to create editable tables

Tags: c#, jquery

I currently have an asp:gridview that is bound to a dataset.  What I need is to be able to click a cell and make it editable, then when focus is lost, the updated field is saved to the database.  If need be, I can change the code from a gridview to something else.  The method isn't important, just the end result.  A table showing data from the database, that allows cells to be edited inline.  Also would need the ability to make some of the editable fields into dropdown lists if possible.  Can anyone help me with this, any suggestions on existing plugins or methods on how to do this without too much complication?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this ( open a editable cell with a double click):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var c = $(document);


    c.on("dblclick","td",function(){ 
        $(this).html("<input type='text' class='txtEdit' />");
    });

    c.on("focusout",".txtEdit",function(){
        var td = $(this).parent("td");
        td.html($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use SlickGrid if you like. http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example3-editing.html

or a little javascript from here http://mrbool.com/how-to-create-an-editable-html-table-with-jquery/27425

```
$(function () {
    $("td").dblclick(function () {
        var OriginalContent = $(this).text();

        $(this).addClass("cellEditing");
        $(this).html("<input type='text' value='" + OriginalContent + "' />");
        $(this).children().first().focus();

        $(this).children().first().keypress(function (e) {
            if (e.which == 13) {
                var newContent = $(this).val();
                $(this).parent().text(newContent);
                $(this).parent().removeClass("cellEditing");
            }
        });

    $(this).children().first().blur(function(){
        $(this).parent().text(OriginalContent);
        $(this).parent().removeClass("cellEditing");
    });
    });
});


Read more: http://mrbool.com/how-to-create-an-editable-html-table-with-jquery/27425#ixzz2g24Rpq6t
```

Answer (score 0):

I made soluton in VS 2010 for you.

http://www.fileconvoy.com/dfl.php?id=gf8df2b85b587e3c2999379985e0a4fcad2e7e3a74

Main idea is to customize your grid (and grid-elements) with 'data' attributes that will contain all neccessary information about field and value to update on server side when editing is finished.

Data posts back to the server via ajax (by jQuery) when dinamically created input losts focus.

Preparing grid:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var ds = new[] { 
                            new { Id = 0, Name = "Joe" }, 
                            new { Id = 1, Name = "Nick" } 
                       };

        GridView1.RowDataBound += new GridViewRowEventHandler(GridView1_RowDataBound);
        GridView1.Attributes.Add("data-upd-route", "GridWorker.aspx");
        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    public void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            e.Row.Attributes.Add("data-id", e.Row.DataItem.GetType().GetProperty("Id").GetValue(e.Row.DataItem, null).ToString());
            e.Row.Cells[1].Attributes.Add("data-col-name", "Name");
            e.Row.Cells[1].Attributes.Add("class", "bg-updatable");
        }
    }
```

jQuery handles client interaction

```
function onGridCellInputBlur(event) {
    var target = $(event.target);

    if (target.val() == target.next().val()) {
        target.closest("td").html(target.next().val());
    }
    else {
        doBackgroundRequest(target);
    }
}

function doBackgroundRequest(descriptiveInitiator) {
var colName = descriptiveInitiator.closest("td").attr("data-col-name");
var colValue = descriptiveInitiator.val();
var entityId = descriptiveInitiator.closest("tr").attr("data-id");
var updRoute = descriptiveInitiator.closest("table").attr("data-upd-route");

$.ajax({
    url: updRoute + "?entityId=" + entityId + "&colName=" + colName + "&colValue=" + colValue,
    type: "POST",
    success: function(p1) {
        descriptiveInitiator.closest("td").html(descriptiveInitiator.val());
    },
    error: function (p1) {
        alert(p1.Message);
    }
    });
}
```

Do some work after post on server side

```
public partial class GridWorker : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var entityId = Request.QueryString["entityId"];
        var colName = Request.QueryString["colName"];
        var colValue = Request.QueryString["colValue"];

        //TODO: do some work
    }
}
```